# How can I resolve the error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'ImageStore'"

Tags: swift

I am working through the following tutorial:
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

In the code snippet below I get the following error:
`Use of unresolved identifier 'ImageStore'`

```
extension Landmark {
    var image: Image {
        ImageStore.shared.image(name: imageName)
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you download the project files for [that tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation), the `ImageStore` class is defined within the `Landmarks/Models/Data.swift` file. Make sure it's included in the correct targets in your local project.

Comment: Oh..!! my mistake sorry TT

Comment: @JangHyo Did you end up working out how to resolve this? I can't find where to add the correct targets